# How to make one logger which can log from different packages to different files

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

So I'm using Log4j2 to log information from my app to some files, but know i want separate the files by packages. I have one logger and i dont know how to make him filter the logs by package/class/

```
<Logger name="hextodec.MainClass" additivity="FALSE">
        <AppenderRef ref="info"  level="INFO"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="error"  level="ERROR"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="stdout" level ="INFO" />
</Logger>
```

Comment: you can use different appenders for different packages, specify each appender-ref for respective package. `<logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="SP_ERROR" />
  <appender-ref ref="SP_DEBUG" />  
  <appender-ref ref="SP_INFO" /> 
</logger>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey this is just for your info, have an idea and implement for your test case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="HIBERNATE_LOG_LOCATION" value="../logs/dev/hibernate" />
    <property name="HIBERNATE_ARCHIVE_LOG_LOCATION" value="../logs/dev/hibernate/archive" />

    <property name="SPRING_LOG_LOCATION" value="../logs/dev/spring" />
    <property name="SPRING_ARCHIVE_LOG_LOCATION" value="../logs/dev/spring/archive" />

<appender name="HIBERNATE_INFO"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${BASE_LOCATION}${HIBERNATE_LOG_LOCATION}/RERUN_UTIL_HIB_INFO.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- hourly rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${BASE_LOCATION}${HIBERNATE_ARCHIVE_LOG_LOCATION}/RERUN_UTIL_HIB_INFO.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.log.gz
            </fileNamePattern>

            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
                <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>

            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>

        <encoder>
            <!-- <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file : %line] %msg%n</pattern> -->
            <pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %class [%M:%L] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <!-- similar appenders for all others -->
<appender name="SP_INFO"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${BASE_LOCATION}${SPRING_LOG_LOCATION}/SPRING_INFO.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- hourly rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${BASE_LOCATION}${SPRING_ARCHIVE_LOG_LOCATION}/SPRING_INFO.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.log.gz
            </fileNamePattern>

            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">

                <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>


            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>

        <encoder>

            <pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %class [%M:%L] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <!-- similar appenders for all others-->

<logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="HIBERNATE_DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="HIBERNATE_INFO" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="HIBERNATE_ERROR" />      
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SP_ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="SP_DEBUG" />     
        <appender-ref ref="SP_INFO" />
    </logger>

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="ERROR" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Hope this solves your quiz.

Comment: Yup, no problems. Always available for questions :) :)

Comment: What if I only want to use one logger?

Comment: Remove other entries and keep the required one. In above example remove  `<logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="HIBERNATE_DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="HIBERNATE_INFO" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="HIBERNATE_ERROR" />      
    </logger>` and use it.

Comment: This is a Logback configuration but a the Log4j 2 equivalent will be very similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating multiple file appenders.

Examples: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Appender Example with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="File" fileName="/var/log/file.log">
       <PatternLayout>
           <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
       </PatternLayout>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.foo.Bar" level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="com.foo.acme" level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: let's say i have a few different appenders, how will the logger distinguish the package if i'm logging from one level